# React/redux app function not firing

Tags: react-redux, es6-promise, redux-form, axios

Update 2:

Another update - I'm down to this one issue. The values from redux-form are being sent to the action, but even narrowed down to this:

```
export function signinUser(values) {
  console.log('function about to run, email: ' values.get('email'));
}
```

**I don't even see a console log entry**. However, the same function with only a simple console log works:

export function signinUser() {
  console.log('function about to run');
}

---

Update:

The only differences between the working code and non-working code is `redux-form` and `immutablejs`. I tried back-porting these to the working app and now the behaviour is the same.

I'm submitting my form and sending the redux-form `values` to the function, where I'm using `values.get('email')` and `values.get('password')` to pass the values to axios.

```
handleFormSubmit(values) {
  console.log('sending to action...', values);
  this.props.signinUser(values);
}
```

---

I have a login form and `onSubmit` I'm passing the values to a function which dispatches actions.

The code works in a repo I've forked, but I'm transferring it to my own app. The problem I'm having is that the function doesn't seem to fire, and I'm struggling to figure out where to add `console.log` statements.

The only `console.log` that fires is on line 2.

```
export function signinUser(values) {
  console.log('function will run');
  return function(dispatch) {
    axios.post(TOKEN_URL, {
      email: "a@a.com",
      password: "a",
      method: 'post',
      credentials: 'include',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
      },
   })
   .then(response => {
     console.log('response: ', response.data.content.token );
     // If request is good...
     // - Update state to indicate user is authenticated
     dispatch({ type: AUTH_USER });

     // decode token for info on the user
     var decoded_token_data = jwt_decode(response.data.content.token);

     // - Save the JWT token
     localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.content.token);
     console.log(localStorage.getItem('token'));
     // - redirect to the appropriate route
     browserHistory.push(ROOT_URL);

   })
   .catch(() => {
     // If request is bad...
     // - Show an error to the user
     dispatch(authError('Bad Login Info'));
   });
  }
}
```

Comment: I updated to redux-form v6.0.0-rc.5 and am having this exact same issue.  It used to fire in the v5 version, but now not.  Any answers?

Comment: First, `console.log('function about to run, email: ', values.get('email'));` you don't see it because you missed the `comma`.. i added it. 

Now, when you receive the response, First check what's the data you actually received from the server, replace `console.log('response: ', response.data.content.token );` with `console.log('response: ', response.data );`

If you don't received the expected response, your code wont work.. as it relies on `response.data.content` to exist.